# Json don´t populate a spinner

Tags: java, android, json, android-spinner

public class FindPlaces extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String MAP_API_URL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id=AW31XQWUOLJWFZCFNZZ04I4IQFUFYIFAFDEHEYITEBBDHIVB&client_secret=R10S3ACA5VFOTGVG2LW1N4YONU30LQ3IE0DKIG1JNHN2QNWE&v=20170811&m=foursquare";
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<String> categoriesList;
ArrayList<Categories> categories;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_places);

    new DownloadJSON().execute();

}
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the Categories Class
        categories = new ArrayList<Categories>();
        // Create an array to populate the spinner
        categoriesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // JSON file URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id=CONSUMER_KEY&client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET&v=20170811&m=foursquare");

        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("categories");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                Categories cat = new Categories();

                cat.setName(jsonobject.optString("name"));

                categories.add(cat);

                // Populate spinner with country names
                categoriesList.add(jsonobject.optString("name"));


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategories);

        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindPlaces.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        categoriesList));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                               View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                        txtname.setText(categories.get(position).getName());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

This is my class to inflate the spinner.

```
public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // Download JSON data from URL
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // Convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

}

This is where i handle with the http request

> {  "response":  {
>       "categories":  [
>          {
>           "id": "4d4b7104d754a06370d81259",
>           "name": "Arts & Entertainment",
>           "pluralName": "Arts & Entertainment",
>           "shortName": "Arts & Entertainment",
>           "icon":  {
>             "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_",
>             "suffix": ".png"
>           },
>           "categories":  [
>              {
>               "id": "56aa371be4b08b9a8d5734db",
>               "name": "Amphitheater",
>               "pluralName": "Amphitheaters",
>               "shortName": "Amphitheater",
>               "icon":  {
>                 "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_",
>                 "suffix": ".png"
>               }

and this is the json.

How can i change to get request instead a post request?
and how can i populate my spinner?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you debugged this? where does it stop working for you? how Get/Post is related to your spinner question

Comment: you are already using a get request as indicated by `new HttpGet(url)`

Comment: jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("categories"); this line i got error. I gues im missing something here. And its related because the foursquare server only accept get method to retrieve the json.